# how do i solve this? using conditionals and return

Tags: python, if-statement

The is_positive function should return True if the number received is positive, otherwise it returns None. Can you fill in the gaps to make that happen?

```
1 def is_positive(number):
2   if ___:
3     return ___
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_positive(number):
   if number > 0:
     return True
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?